# MethodHandle cast return type

Tags: java, methodhandle

I try to link methods together through methodhandles, some of them are from generic types. If a function returns a generic type I have to specify Object.class for the MethodType but I see no easy way to convert it back into the generic type parameter type. In most cases it's no problem because invoke seem to convert them automatically but I must create mhs which could be run with invokeExact. Is there no easy way to cast with methodhandles?

My testcode:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
    class Prefixer {
        public static String prefix(String s) {
            return "Number: " + s;
        }
    }
    IntFunction<String> converter = Integer::toString;

    var lookup = MethodHandles.lookup();
    var prefixMH = lookup.findStatic(Prefixer.class, "prefix", MethodType.methodType(String.class, String.class));

    var converterMH = lookup.findVirtual(IntFunction.class, "apply", MethodType.methodType(Object.class, int.class));
    converterMH = converterMH.bindTo(converter);

    /* Doesn't work because converter is a (int)Object and no (int)String
    var mh = MethodHandles.filterArguments(prefixMH, 0, converterMH);
     */

    /* Does work for invoke but not for invokeExact
    var prefixCasted = MethodHandles.explicitCastArguments(prefixMH, MethodType.methodType(String.class, Object.class));
    var mh = MethodHandles.filterArguments(prefixCasted, 0, converterMH);
    */
    /* Does work for invoke but not for invokeExact */
    var mh = MethodHandles.filterArguments(prefixMH, 0, converterMH.asType(MethodType.methodType(String.class, int.class)));

    System.out.println(mh.invoke(12));
    System.out.println(mh.invokeExact(42));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code looks okay to me, you just need to use a cast at the call site as well:

```
System.out.println((String) mh.invokeExact(42));
```

Otherwise the type at the call site will be `(int)Object` which doesn't match the type of the MethodHandle `(int)String` and you get a WMTE.

The `invoke` version of the call you have:

```
System.out.println(mh.invoke(12));
```

Will implicitly convert the type of `mh` into `(int)Object` (the type of the call site) using an `asType` call, and then invoke the resulting method handle.

If you want to do that explicitly and use `invokeExact` you could do:

```
mh = mh.asType(MethodType.methodType(Object.class, int.class));
System.out.println(mh.invokeExact(42));
```