# WrongMethodTypeException with MethodHandle.invokeExact() but no arguments and return type is same

Tags: java, reflection, methodhandle

I'm using Java 17 on AWS Lambda. I have an interface `Foo` with a method `bar()`, returning a `CompletableFuture<Map<Bar, Long>>`:

```java
public interface Foo {
  public CompletableFuture<Map<Bar, Long>> bar();
}
```

In the `MyProcessor` class, I have an instance reference to an implemention of `Foo` which is `FooImpl`:

```java
class MyProcessor {

  private final Foo foo;

  MyProcessor() {
    foo = goGetFooImpl();
  }

  void doSomething() {
    …
  }

}
```

Finally in `MyProcessor.doSomething()`, I look up the `Foo.bar()` method and try to invoke it using a method handle (leaving out exception handling for clarity):

```java
  //filter out the only method with the name "bar"
  Method barMethod = foo.getClass().getDeclaredMethods().…;
  MethodHandle = MethodHandles.lookup().unreflect(barMethod);
  CompletableFuture<?> result = (CompletableFuture<?>)methodHandle.invokeExact(foo);
```

The error message is odd:

> `java.lang.invoke.WrongMethodTypeException: expected (FooImpl)CompletableFuture but found (Foo)CompletableFuture`

I realize with `MethodHandle.invokeExact()` that the arguments and return type must be exact. In this case there are no arguments. And it is my understanding that the generic type of `CompletableFuture` is erased at runtime; thus in this case the concrete return type is the same. So what is the problem?

What does the error message mean when it mentions `(Fooimpl)` and `(Foo)`? How does the type of the target impact the type of `CompletableFuture`?

I realize that the `bar()` method is declared on `Foo`, but looked up that method on the class of an instance of `FooImpl`. But why would that be a problem? From the documentation I had understood that `MethodHandle.invokeExact()` works on virtual methods.

I can call `methodHandle.invoke(foo)` here and it works fine, but not `methodHandle.invokeExact(foo)`. What is not "exact" about what I'm doing? Does anyone know what the error message means?

I found [MethodHandle cast return type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67445901) which appears to be related, but I'm still not getting it. A `CompletableFuture` is a `CompletableFuture`. Since when is there such things as `(Foo)CompletableFuture` and `(FooImpl)CompletableFuture` and why would they be different?

Answer (score 4):

`invokeExact` really means that the static type of the argument must match the type of the MethodHandle exactly. `Foo` and `FooImpl` are not the same type. See also [the doc of `invokeExact`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandle.html#invokeExact(java.lang.Object...)):

> The symbolic type descriptor at the call site of invokeExact must
> exactly match this method handle's type. No conversions are allowed on
> arguments or return values.

The symbolic descriptor for `invokeExact` is derived from the static types of the arguments and return value at the call site. In your case that is `(Foo)CompletableFuture`, taking 1 argument of type `Foo` and returning `CompletableFuture` (you could also inspect the type descriptor using `javap` to disassemble the class file). See also the doc section on Signature Polymorphism: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandle.html#sigpoly

`invoke` automatically applies the type conversion from `Foo` to `FooImpl`, so that works.

If you're only invoking the MethodHandle once using `invoke` is fine. If you plan on invoking it many times you could erase the type of the receiver to `Foo` to avoid the type conversion:

```
//filter out the only method with the name "bar"
Method barMethod = foo.getClass().getDeclaredMethods().…;
MethodHandle methodHandle = MethodHandles.lookup().unreflect(barMethod);
methodHandle = methodHandle.asType(methodHandle.type().changeParameterType(0, Foo.class));
CompletableFuture<?> result = (CompletableFuture<?>)methodHandle.invokeExact(foo);
```

Comment: Oh, so the error message means that the target object I passed as a parameter to `invokeExact()` was expected to be a `FooImpl`, but I passed it a reference to a `Foo` (even though it was an implementation of `FooImpl`). The error message made it seems like it had something to do with the return type `CompletableFuture`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion; the `changeParameterType(…)` method looks really useful! However once this code is done I may not know about `Foo.class` directly. Can I go in the opposite direction? Since I know the type of `foo` at runtime, can I simply use `foo.getClass().cast(foo)` before I pass it to `invokeExact(…)`? Won't that cast it to a `FooImpl` as `invokeExact(…)` is expecting? That is, won't it put `foo` in the same type terms I started with when I used `foo.getClass().getDeclaredMethods()`?

Comment: Update: Nope, passing `foo.getClass().cast(foo)` didn't work. I guess I'll have to go the `changeParameterType(…)` route to update the type of the method handle. I guess if I create `FooImpl` dynamically, e.g. `Class.forName(…)`, then the declared type of the reference to `FooImpl` will be `Object`, not `Foo`. But surely I can't change the method handle parameter type to `Object` can I? I'll have to experiment with this further, but I think you gave me the crucial information to allow me to look into it more.

Comment: I would recommend just using `.invoke`.  IIRC, it caches the type conversion so you don't have to do the manual conversion yourself.

Comment: @GarretWilson if you don’t know about `Foo`, how could you know about `FooImpl` at the same time? And, of course, `foo.getClass().cast(foo)` does not affect what you know at compile-time. No runtime operation can do that. You can change the type of the method handle to `Object`, that’s like injecting a type cast into the result handle. Or just use `invoke` instead of `invokeExact`. Or use `invoke` on the `Method` you had to begin with. It’s not clear why you’re insisting on `invokeExact`.

Comment: It might be easier to just use `Foo.class.getDeclaredMethod("bar")`. But then you can avoid all of this by just using `foo.bar()`.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn since it’s an interface, even `Foo.class.getMethod("bar")` would do. But this assumes that `Foo` is in scope. But your comment hits a good point. `foo.getClass().getDeclaredMethod[s](…)` gets handles to methods bound to `FooImpl`. So the answer’s `.asType(methodHandle.type().changeParameterType(0, Foo.class))` is not different to the `.asType(methodHandle.type().changeParameterType(0, Object.class))` the OP might need. In either case, the parameter type is widened and a type cast to `FooImpl` injected. It’s important to understand that `Foo` has no significance to the handle here

Comment: I tried to simplify the example in the question to get to the cause of the problem. As for the solution, in my actual use case I may not know the types of `FooImpl` or `Foo` ahead of time. I may not even know types of parameters `Foo.bar()` is _supposed_ to have. I may only have 1) the name of `FooImpl`, 2) the name of the method and 3) some typeless marshaled forms of the parameters. Thus if I create `FooImpl` using `ClassForName(…)` or equivalent and find the method, it looks like using `.asType(methodHandle.type().changeParameterType(0, Object.class))` may be what I'll need to do.

Comment: "Or use `invoke` on the `Method` you had to begin with." I am creating an abstract invocation layer in a larger framework that uses a consistent invocation approach, without knowing how the method handles were derived. This layer may cache the method handles. Furthermore it is my understanding, despite several blogs citing tests to the contrary, that eventually the JVM will be able to invoke method handles in a much more efficient manner. (I've read that eventually the JDK will re-implement `Method` invocation to use method handles anyway, but I need to choose one or the other in this layer.)

Comment: @GarretWilson The re-implementation has already been done in Java 18: https://openjdk.org/jeps/416 It is true that MethodHandles can be more efficient, but this is typically only the case when the receiver method handle at a call site is a constant. e.g. it is stored in a `static final` field. Or, if you're binding arguments to a method handle using `MethodHandles::insertArguments` and invoking the result many times (at least 127).