# "Cannot cast [Ljava.lang.Object;" passing Object[] to Object... varargs

Tags: java, arrays, methodhandle

I'm struggling with a simple, fundamental Java language question that isn't making sense. I'm passing an `Object[]` to a method which expects varargs `Object...`, but the method seems to be interpreting the request as `new Object[]{Object[]}`. That is, instead of considering the `Object[]` as equivalent to `Object...`, it seems to be passing the `Object[]` as the first element of the varargs, thus wrapping the `Object[]` in another array of objects.

I have the following in Java 17:

```java
FooImpl foo = goGetFooImpl();
List<?> methodArgs = List.of(); //no method args
Object[] invokeArgs = Stream.concat(Stream.of(foo, methodArgs.stream()).toArray();
// this gives me the equivalent of `new Object[]{foo}`
// logging `List.of(invokeArgs)` shows `[com.example.FooImpl@…]`
MethodHandle barMethodHandle = goLookUpMethodHandle(foo, "bar");
methodHandle.invoke(invokeArgs); //expects varargs `foo, arg1, arg2, …`
```

I get:

> `java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast [Ljava.lang.Object; to com.example.FooImpl`

The method signature I'm calling is `MethodHandle.invoke(Object... args)`. It expects varargs, with the first object referencing the target object on which the method is being invoked. So this works:

```java
FooImpl foo = goGetFooImpl();
MethodHandle barMethodHandle = goLookUpMethodHandle(foo, "bar");
barMethodHandle.invoke(foo);
```

In this case I don't know ahead of time that there are no further arguments (i.e. `methodArgs` above might not be empty), which is why I combined everything into an `Object[]`. But even manually testing like this doesn't work:

```java
FooImpl foo = goGetFooImpl();
MethodHandle barMethodHandle = goLookUpMethodHandle(foo, "bar");
barMethodHandle.invoke(new Object[]{foo});
```

The reason this is confusing me is that this is such a basic Java issue (a newbie question, really), and I have understood for years that Java would *by default* consider passing `Object[]` to a method expecting `Object...` to be equivalent. I had believed that I would have to cast `Object[]` to `Object` using `(Object)invokeArgs` in order for it to be considered the first object of the `Object...` (which I don't want). But this seems to be happening anyway without the cast.

The error message seems to be telling me that Java is considering `Object[]` to be the first Object of the `Object...` varargs, because the method seems to be trying to convert the `invokeArgs` *itself* (which is a `Object[]`) to a reference to `FooImpl`, which is what is requested as the first argument in the varargs.

This doesn't make sense to me. Either I've misunderstood for years how varargs works, or something weird is going on with the `MethodHandle.invoke(…)` method specifically, or I'm just having a mental blank.

Even if `MethodHandle.invoke(…)` has some sort of special behavior, aren't the arguments determined at compile time? How could `MethodHandle.invoke(…)` have different behavior based upon whether I use `invoke(foo)` or `invoke(new Object[]{foo})`? During compilation aren't they equivalent, and in either case the compiler will wind up passing `new Object[]{foo}` to the method, even in the case of `invoke(foo)`?

Comment: This is not remotely a newbie question because MethodHandle.invoke works differently from literally any other method in Java.  Its rules are different and complicated, and it is quite likely "something weird is going on with it specifically."  Have you tried invokeWithArguments instead?

Comment: I understand that `MethodHandle.invoke(…)` works in strange and wondrous ways _inside it_, but I don't understand how that would affect the compiler's interpretation of how arguments are passed _to it_. I don't see how the internals of `MethodHandle.invoke(…)` could have any bearing on compiler method matching and interpretation of parameters—isn't that determined at compile time? I haven't looked at `invokeWithArguments(…)`; I'll go check that out now, thanks.

Comment: Put another way, how could `MethodHandle.invoke(…)` have different behavior based upon whether I use `invoke(foo)` or `invoke(new Object[]{foo})`? During compilation aren't they equivalent, and in either case the compiler will wind up passing `new Object[]{foo}` to the method, even in the case of `invoke(foo)`?

Comment: @GarretWilson, there is a typo in your first code example, _"... String List<?> methodArgs = List.of(); //no method args ..."_.  And, you are using a _concat_ method on a _Stream#of_ call.  Did you mean to use _[Stream#concat](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#concat(java.util.stream.Stream,java.util.stream.Stream))_ instead?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo; I've fixed it now. Yes, I had statically imported `Stream.concat(…)`. I have now made that explicit.

Comment: "During compilation aren't they equivalent, and in either case the compiler will wind up passing new Object[]{foo} to the method, even in the case of invoke(foo)? " - No. `MethodHandles.invoke` is a `@SignaturePolymorphic` method, where there is a difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> or something weird is going on with the MethodHandle.invoke(…) method specifically

Yes! The signature of `MethodHandle::invoke` is a lie. It is not a `Object...` varargs method, and it does not return `Object` either. Both the formal parameters and the return type are placeholders. This is because `MethodHandle::invoke` is a signature polymorphic method.

See [section 15.12.3 of the Java language spec (se20)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.3). Quoted here, I've omitted the irrelevant parts:

> A method is *signature polymorphic* if all of the following are true:
>
> - It is declared in the `java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle` class or the `java.lang.invoke.VarHandle` class.
> - It has a single variable arity parameter ([§8.4.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.1)) whose declared type is `Object[]`.
> - It is `native`.

This affects how the he *compile-time parameter types* and *compile-time result* are determined:

> - If the compile-time declaration for the method invocation is a signature polymorphic method, then:
>
>   - The compile-time parameter types are the types of the actual argument expressions. ...
>   - The compile-time result is determined as follows:
>
>     ...
>
>     - Otherwise, if the method invocation expression is an expression statement, the compile-time result is `void`.

(See also the section of the `MethodHandle` javadoc on [signature polymorphism](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandle.html#sigpoly))

In your case the type of the single actual argument expression is `Object[]`, so the type of the invocation is `(Object[])void`.

The invocation then fails because the implementation of `invoke` tries to automatically adapt the argument type to the parameter [type](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandle.html#type()) of the method handle, which is `com.example.FooImpl`. For reference types this is done using a cast, as explained in the documentation of [`MethodHandle::asType`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandle.html#asType(java.lang.invoke.MethodType)). Since `Object[]` can not be cast to `FooImpl`, you get the `ClassCastException`.

As @Louis Wasserman says in the comments: if you want the `Object[]` to be expanded into a list of arguments you need to use `MethodHandle::invokeWithArguments`.

Comment: "The signature of `MethodHandle::invoke` is a lie. It is not a `Object... varargs` method … [T]he `Object[]` you pass … is not expanded into a list of arguments like what would normally happen …."  I'm speechless. Wow. Thanks for that clarification. I'll go read up on all this. Otherwise, I don't know what to say. That was totally unexpected!

Comment: So, the `PolymorphicSignature` is a culprit here - it  indicates that a method can have different signatures depending on the context.

Comment: I don't want to judge too much this before going and reading up on it, but to have an annotation completely change how compile-time signature binding works seems like a throwback to sort of the magical, special things the language did for serialization (e.g. special fields, special methods, etc.). It doesn't feel right. But again I'll go research it and maybe I'll love it—who knows. Thanks again to everyone in cluing me in on what is happening.

Comment: @GarretWilson The main advantage of signature polymorphism is, for one, that if you pass a primitive argument, it will not have to be boxed into an object (e.g. no need to convert `int` to `Integer`). But also: it allows the runtime to generate the implementation of the method on demand, based on the specific type of the invocation. This means that a sigpoly method can have many different implementations, all with a different type. Where each implementation is specialized for exactly that type. Both these things are very useful features for maximizing performance.

Comment: `invokeWithArguments(invokeArgs)` works!  And it's even nicer, because it has a `List<?>` variation so I wouldn't even need to convert to `Object[]`. But I wonder how I would pass everything if I wanted to use `invokeExact(…)`,seeing that there is no `invokeExactWithArguments(…)` variation. Perhaps using something like `methodHandle.bind(foo).invokeExact(myArgArray)`? (As I mentioned, I'll go research all this and probably find the answer.)

Comment: @GarretWilson `invokeExact` matches up the types of the argument expressions with the type of the method handle. If they don't match, an exception is thrown. But, if you pass the arguments in a list using `invokeWithArguments`, there are no argument expressions besides the `List`. So there is nothing to check against.

Comment: It is absolutely special and extralinguistic, but it exists in the language to be the basis for a number of important use cases for which the overhead of boxing isn't acceptable.

Comment: @GarretWilson [you can make a handle accepting an array](https://ideone.com/ZVPxsQ) but it’s confusing to see you expecting a varargs behavior, after the discussion in [your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77060436/2711488) about the compiler taking the exact compile-time types of the arguments. You should also be aware that when you inject all the behavior of `Method.invoke` (vargs + boxing) into the method handle call, you can’t expect a better performance than `Method.invoke` for the call. So you’re making your life unnecessary hard by not using `Method.invoke`.

Comment: "… your earlier question about the compiler taking the exact compile-time types of the arguments." My earlier question was about matching types _after they are passed_ to `Method.invoke(…)`. To me whether these exact arguments are passed via varargs or `Object[]` or `List<?>` to me is an orthogonal issue, and shouldn't have any bearing on whether the objects being passed _inside_ the data structure are exact matches or not. Perhaps this new signature polymorphism conflates the two concepts somewhat, which is what was confusing me.

Comment: "… when you inject all the behavior … into the method handle call, you can’t expect a better performance than `Method.invoke` for the call. So you’re making your life unnecessary hard by not using `Method.invoke`." Ah, good to know; I'll take that into consideration. In summary, I'm going to be creating an abstraction layer and I wanted to use the latest and most efficient method invocation feature, so these two questions were partly experimenting with the best approach for that. This discussion will help me make the best decision on which mechanism to use in this layer, thanks.